# Raspberry Pi 3 not detecting i2c device

Tags: python, pi-3, i2c

I've been following a tutorial to hook up an electronic compass that relays info to the Pi via i2c. The only differences between my equipment and the tutorial's is that I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 with Python 3 already installed, and the HMC5883L compass I am using has been bundled with a few more sensors than that being used in the tutorial.

I've triple checked my connections, and am certain that VCC is hooked up to 3.3V, GND to GDN, SDA to SDA, and SCL to SCL.

[image: The back of the compass]

I have confirmed that `i2c-tools` and `libi2c-dev` are installed, as well as `python-smbus`.

`i2c-dev`and `i2c-bcm2708` have been added to `/etc/modules`

`dtparam=i2c_arm=on`and `dtparam=i2c1=on`have been added to `/boot/config.txt`

`i2c-bcm2708`has been removed from the blacklist.

However, when I type the

```
i2cdetect -y 1
```

command, all I see is an empty address field.

**UPDATE**

It has been brought up that this is an SPI device and not an i2c device. I am not sure if that is the issue, as the [vendor page](http://www.uctronics.com/10dof-imu-ms5611-hmc5883l-mpu6050-sensor-module-p-857l.html) says that it outputs in the i2c format. In addition, the data sheet the vendor provides for the compass on the sensor directly describes the compass as an i2c device.

More explicitly, my question is "how to I get the Raspberry Pi 3 to recognize an i2c device?"

**FIX**

Connecting the chip directly to the SDA and SCL from the Pi to the chip with no breadboard intermediate fixed the problem. wat

Comment: How are the pins labelled on the sensor and have you a link to the sensor specs?

Comment: Hi. The spec sheets are available to download from the vendor's page [here](http://www.uctronics.com/9dof-itg3205-adxl345-hmc5883l-gyro-accel-compass-sensor-module-for-arduino.html).

The pins are labeled VCC_IN, 3.3V, GND, SCL, SDA, FSYNC,INTA, DRDY

Comment: No offense, I know you said you triple-checked the connections, but if pinouts on your module are the same as the module in the tutorial, it sure looks to me like your SDA and SCL are reversed. Going by the pin labels shown in the tutorial, starting at the edge of the board, VCC, GND, SCL, SDA. This is also what you've described above, but in your picture the 3rd wire in (purple, SCL) is going to the second pin in (pin #3) on the GPIO header (SDA).

Comment: No offense taken, but after checking again, I can confirm that all input to the chip are correct.

Comment: The linked device is SPI not I2C.  Could you add or change the photo so we can see the pin labels and the wire colours so we can trace from sensor pin to Pi pin?

Comment: It looks to me like that is the answer.  If you can demonstrate you are using an I2C device, connected correctly, by including a picture of the bottom of the board, etc., this question can be reopened.

Comment: I cannot both add a picture of the bottom of the board as well as proof this is an i2c device due to not being allowed to show more than two links. I have opted to link to the vendor page and explicitly write out what the pins are on the chip. Is this sufficient to take the question off of hold status?

Comment: You can remove the pointless picture you have there now and replace it with one that communicates actual information.  Currently you are more or less saying, "I am positive I have done everything right yet it does not work" -> Then either you are wrong, or the hardware is broken.  If you want to choose the last option, you do not have a question.  If you want to choose the former one, you have to provide a means by which other people can check your work.

Comment: BTW, if the pin ordering is correct, as has already been observed, **you have SCL and SDA backward.** The white wire is connected to SDA on the device but SCL on the Pi.

Comment: I genuinely apologize for my lackluster documentation and appreciate your efforts to help me. SCL and SDA were indeed backwards in the previous picture, however that was because I switched them whilst attempting to debug before making the post and didn't switch them back for the picture. I apologize for this, however my issue still persists with them in the correct order. 

How would I test my SDA and SCL pins for hardware issues? I cannot set them to high using GPIO, is this indicative of a hardware issue?

Comment: Never mind, I have been able to set the SDA SCL pins to high and low using GPIO. I am doing something wrong but I cannot figure out what it is. The i2cdetect command works, so i2c is indeed enabled, the device is an i2c device according the the vendor, and I have confirmed the device is connected to the Raspberry Pi (again, sorry for the confusing documentation on my part), and confirmed that the SDA and SCL pins are functional. I am in the process of re-installing Raspian and duplicating everything I've previously done.

Comment: Re-checked all work, re-installed Raspian and i2c related software, confirmed SDA and SCL pins are functional, confirmed chip is getting power, checked that I didn't switch "l" with "1" in any commands, made sure nothing was on the black-list, added initializing the i2c kernal upon boot, added i2c relevant modules, but it is still not being detected. 

Is a hardware issue with the actual sensor itself the only explanation?

Comment: What is the operating system you are using?  you most active i2c port in the kernel (use `sudo raspi-config`)

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please see my comment on your other question: no meta tags in the title please. If your answer fully addresses the question consider accepting it to mark the question as "answered" instead.

Comment: Any piece of metal has some built in capacitance and inductance. It could be the case that in this scenario, the breadboard is introducing too much capacitance and inductance and messing up your signal. It's not uncommon, especially in higher speed communication. I would comment instead of posting this as an answer.. but I can't :)

Answer (score 4):

**[FIXED]**

I've fixed the problem, but I don't know what it was.

It turns out there was an issue passing the SDA and SCL line through a breadboard. The chip was still getting power through the breadboard, however SDA and SCL were not getting through.

Moving the chip to a different position on the breadboard, and to different breadboard completely still messed up the connection.

The solution was to connect the pinouts on the RPi 3 DIRECTLY to the chip, and I am now able to interact with the device.

Thanks to everyone who commented and helped me get this working, but honestly this solution is just raising more questions than answers. o_O

Comment: A breadboard adds capacitance to the circuit. That could have been enough to mess up the high-speed connection.

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours trying to solve that problem today. The issue was also some bad connections in the breadboard. If you face this problem, make sure that both your VCC and GROUND of the device is connected to the Raspberry Pi and also try pushing / moving a little bit the device in the breadboard to see if the i2cdetect identifies it.

Answer (score 0):

enable I2C in the kernel

```
 sudo raspi-config
```

and find advanced options (Number 8) -> I2C (A7) -> enable I2c interface (Yes)

Installing Kernel Support (Manually)

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

and add to file

```
i2c-bcm2708&nbsp;
i2c-dev
```

exit and save (ctrl + X ->Y)

reboot your raspberry 
`sudo reboot`

please visit this page

[Tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c)

Comment: If the i2c_detect command works without complaining about a missing bus it indicates that I2C has been configured properly.

Comment: most active i2c port in the kernel otherwise OS not find I2C port

Comment: I'm just pointing out the questioner must have properly enabled I2C.  If he hadn't he would have got an error message when he ran i2c_detect (as mentioned in the question).

Comment: Yes, you are right. But still, I believe must be enabled in the kernels. I tried :/ @joan

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a combination of loose wires and a chip **(SC16IS750)** which can be set to I2C or SPI. The pin was floating so the device was in a state of limbo.

**From the datasheet:**
I2C-bus or SPI interface select. I2C-bus interface is selected if
this pin is at logic HIGH. SPI interface is selected if this pin is at
logic LOW.