# i2c not detecting ADS1115

Tags: pi-4, i2c

I am using ADS1015 with my RPi4. A couple weeks ago there were no problem with the i2c module,(the components were not connected when not used), but since last week it is not detecting my device. I tried many things, including ordering a new ADS(also not detected), many different cables, and also many solutions found on this forum.
What could be my issue?

Wiring:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWXfG.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHyLn.jpg

Device End:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMzbj.jpg
sudo i2cdetect -y 1:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgGKi.jpg

`/boot/config.txt`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJNhb.jpg

`/etc/modules`:https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcJUj.jpg

`lsmod`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQddA.jpg

Already tried :
[i2c not detecting any connections](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49982/i2c-not-detecting-any-connections)
[https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66145/raspberry-pi-3-not-`detecting-i2c-device`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66145/raspberry-pi-3-not-%60detecting-i2c-device%60)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42904712/i2c-not-detecting-issues-in-hardware-or-any-other

Comment: i also tried if i killed my gpios: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=180505

Comment: Please any terminal output as text to your Question.

Comment: when i try to run some code which needs input from my ADC i get:TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Conncetion timed out

Answer (score 0):

It's important to clearly show the connections made to devices so we can clearly see which Pi Pin is connected to which device pin.

In this case the problem appears to be at the device end.  The wires are not connected to the device pins.  The header pins may be through the through-hole plating - it does not mean they are connected.  You need to solder the header pins to the device.

Comment: i havent soldered before and i used the same setup for nearly 2 months. could it happen that for 2 months the device was "accidentally" connected?

Comment: It has happened, little point arguing about it.

Comment: well i soldered, and it was not the issue it is still not able to detect. i also uploaded an other angle of the pin layout, maybe you can see it better now

Comment: The problem was at the device end.  That's the end we need to see.

Comment: Unfortunately those connections look fine at both ends now.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?  I used your GPIO test, but that did not included "non - user gpios". Is there a chance that i killed one of those? Is there a method to check it?

Comment: Looking at config.txt the I2C baud rate seems low at 10k rather than 100k.  Any reason not to use the default?  The non-user GPIO would not affect I2C.

Comment: Yes, it was a suggestion on another question

Comment: I'd change it back or remove the line.

Comment: I changed it back to 100 000. Now the i2cdetect shows an adress https://imgur.com/a/izwkvmj although , when i try to run a demo code for ADS1115 it throws me OSError:  [Errno 121]: Remote I/O Error

Comment: 0x4b is a slightly strange address.  Is that the address the demo code is using? Personally I'd connect the ADDR pin to ground to force address 0x48.

Comment: i rebooted the RPi to see if my other ADC(ADS1015) also showed this 0x4B ( it doesnt) then after connecting the ADS1115 back again it didnt not showed this 0x4b again. another suspicios behavior of the RPi is that when i type the sudo i2cdetect it loads the addresses slowly one by one

Answer (score 0):

I will take a SWAG and say the way it is operating is indicative of an open/intermittent circuit or marginal voltage on the I2C High. I did not see any pull up resistors. They should be in the 3K range to the 3V3 power supply. The select jumpers should be installed at least for the initial debugging as without link to the technical information on the part I have to assume it is floating as the I2C pins as well.